# Como gerar PDF com pouca memória no servidor?

Tags: php, pdf

Estou a passar uma tabela da minha BD para PDF e estou a usar o [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/).

Só que primeiro tenho de passar a minha tabela para HTML e só depois consigo passar para PDF, o que acarreta uso de muita **memória** e eu tenho poucos recursos no servidor (256M para o PHP no máximo).

Como posso  passar uma tabela que pode ter milhares de registos para PDF com 256M de memória no máximo, no PHP?

Comment: Eu só usei o mpdf num projeto. Me atendeu as necessidades!

Comment: Difícil tem uma resposta correta, sem fazer teste de carga. Não acredito que existirão respostas que considerem todas as opções e que não sejam apenas opinião pessoal. Minha sugestão: Teste todas estes componentes e anote os números.

Comment: Minha sugestão, quem for responder faça os testes de carga e poste os resultados :D

Answer (score 2):

Já tive o mesmo problema. Resolvi usando o Snappy que gera o PDF de uma forma diferente, utilizando pouca memória.

A biblioteca pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy).

Instalando via composer:

```
$ composer require knplabs/knp-snappy
```

É necessário os aplicativos Wkhtmltopdf e Wkhtmltoimage, disponíveis para Windows Linux e OS X disponíveis [aqui](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

Incluindo e usando a biblioteca no seu projeto:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

//adicione o caminho para o seu wkhtmltopdf como no exemplo abaixo
$snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');

//configure a pasta temporária para salvar o arquivo
$snappy->generateFromHtml($html, '/tmp/arquivo.pdf');

//force o download do arquivo
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
readfile('/tmp/file.pdf);
```

[Neste link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_K4SZ8a895JUEJna2dCLUg1YkE) disponibilizei a pasta com os arquivos caso não consiga baixar. Extraia o arquivo e coloque a pasta `vendor` e a pasta `wkhtmltox` na raiz do seu projeto.

O caminho do wkhtmltopdf será `'__DIR__./wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf'`

Answer (score 1):

Eu sempre uso o MPDF, em questão de memória você pode aumentar o tamanho máximo de alocação de memória no PHP com o `ini_set("memory_limit","120M");` ou o tamanho que achar necessário, em questão de performance não posso fazer uma comparação com essas outras classes por não ter usado outras em quaisquer projetos meu.

Comment: Não posso nada aumentar o tamanho da memoria, eu disse em cima na pergunta.